# How do I pass my arrays to my other functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

So I am having a problem with passing my arrays to my functions and I cant seem to get it to work

I have this so far...

```
int getProfit();
int getTotal();

int main(){

  int profits[12];
  string monthNames[12] = {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
  int quarterProfits[4];

  cout << "Welcome to my comic store!\n" << endl;

  getProfit();
  getTotal();

}

int getProfit(){

  for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    cout << "Enter the profit for month " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
    cin >> profits[i];

    if(profits[i] < 0){
      cout << "Invalid profit! Please enter the profit for month " << i + 1 << ": "<< endl;
      cin >> profits[i];
    }
  }
}

int getTotal(){
  int profitTotal = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    profitTotal = profitTotal + profits[i];
  }
  return profitTotal;
}
```

So right now I am trying to pass my profits array to my getTotal function but nothing I try seems to work.

I think the problem may be that I am getting my profits array from another function (getProfit), but i'm not sure.

Any improvements or suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: `int profits[12]` is a local variable in `main()`. Hence, no other function may access it. You have to pass it as argument to other functions if it should be used in them. E.g. `int getProfit(int profits[])`. (Please, note that C arrays are never passed by value but by pointer instead. So, the input in `getProfit(int profits[])` will modify the array it is called with.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not declaring profits as a parameter, a function does not know about its environment only about its parameters and what it is supposed to do, so, you have to send the array as a parameter

```cpp
/*
call it in the main function as
getProfit(profits); (don't forget modify the prototype)

Note: do it same in getTotal
*/
int getProfit(int *profits) {

  for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    cout << "Enter the profit for month " << i + 1 << ": " << endl;
    cin >> profits[i];

    while (profits[i] < 0) {//if only checks once
      cout << "Invalid profit! Please enter the profit for month " << i + 1 << ": ";
      cin >> profits[i];
    }
  }
}
```

See [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/) for further information about pointers and arrays